# IDE errors shows up only in production, not sandbox

Tags: force.com, ide, metadata

I've been able to update meta data on standard object picklist values and refresh them to our full sandbox, but am unable to do the same thing in production with out the following errors.

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed
>   File only saved locally, not to server

And when I attempt to do a 'Save to Server', a dialog box opens titled 'Confirm Save Dirty Resource', stating 'Save resource is dirty'.

Any ideas or workarounds for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I was finally able to migrate my meta-data updates on picklist values** on the standard objects such as 'Leads', 'Contacts' etc. by doing
>   a '**Deploy to Server' when selecting objects and right clicking on them and choosing 'Deploy to Server' from the 'force.com' menu**.

- I do believe that **@Mike Chale had a good point that the errors I was experiencing, from just refresh was due to time stamps on meta data differences between my local copy and that of the production server.**

So after taking some initial precautions in backing up data and testing 'Deploy to Server' on non critical objects and the sandbox, I overcame my fear and proceeded to deploy to production.

Also this takes a degree of patience as the IDE has to run through a series of debug tests against 'Referenced Packages' but this is just standard, and then generates a debug and deployment log. The deployment log is good as it will actually name the meta data objects you deployed and describe success or failure, it also updates the entire package.xml that describes only the objects you updated.

Answer (score 1):

The `System.AssertException` sounds like a unit test is failing and the "dirty resource" sounds like your local copy is older than what is on the server.

Do you have any code or test classes that rely on certain picklist values? Have you tried syncing your local files from the server (make sure you backup the local copies first)?

Comment: Yes, upon synchronization the IDE just shows the changes I've made to the xml nodes, remote to local. The code is fine. Do you think I could safely backup my meta data and then run the 'Save to Server' despite the warnings? If it is the local copy showing up as older, how could I alleviate that? Is there something wrong with time stamps from local to production? (thanks)

Comment: I'd make copies and then on the affected files right-click, choose force.com->refresh from server. That should ensure there is no sync problem.